# How to round the results of a GLM predict in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to do a very simple Logistic regression in Julia.  But Julia's typing system seems to be causing me problems.  Basically, glm predict gives me an array of probabilities.  I want to do a simple round so that if the probability >= 0.5, it is a 1, otherwise a 0.  I would like those labels to also be integers.

No matter what I do, I can't convert the DataArray returned by predict to Int64. If I create an adhoc DataArray, I can round it just fine.  Even though they both show a type of DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}.  I've also tried things like pred>0.5, but that fails similarly. Clearly there is some magic with the return value from predict, beyond the type, that makes it different than the other DataArray in my short program.

```
using DataFrames;
using GLM;

df = readtable("./data/titanic-dataset.csv");

delete!(df, :PassengerId);
delete!(df, :Name);
delete!(df, :Ticket);
delete!(df, :Cabin);
pool!(df, [:Sex]);
pool!(df, [:Embarked]);
df[isna.(df[:Age]),:Age] = median(df[ .~isna.(df[:Age]),:Age])

model = glm(@formula(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked), df, Binomial(), LogitLink());
pred = predict(model,df);

z = DataArray([1.0,2.0,3.0]);
println(typeof(z));
println(typeof(pred));
println(round.(Int64,z));  # Why does this work?
println(round.(Int64,pred)); # But this does not?
```

The output is:

```
DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}
DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}
[1, 2, 3]
MethodError: no method matching round(::Type{Int64}, ::DataArrays.NAtype)
Closest candidates are:
  round(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::Integer) where T<:Integer at int.jl:408
  round(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::Float16) where T<:Integer at float.jl:338
  round(::Type{T<:Union{Signed, Unsigned}}, ::BigFloat) where T<:Union{Signed, Unsigned} at mpfr.jl:214
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at C:\Users\JHeaton\.julia\v0.6\DataArrays\src\broadcast.jl:32 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion at .\cartesian.jl:64 [inlined]
 [3] macro expansion at C:\Users\JHeaton\.julia\v0.6\DataArrays\src\broadcast.jl:111 [inlined]
 [4] _broadcast!(::DataArrays.##116#117{Int64,Base.#round}, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\JHeaton\.julia\v0.6\DataArrays\src\broadcast.jl:67
 [5] broadcast!(::Function, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}, ::Type{Int64}, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\JHeaton\.julia\v0.6\DataArrays\src\broadcast.jl:169
 [6] broadcast(::Function, ::Type{T} where T, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}) at .\broadcast.jl:434
 [7] include_string(::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:515
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create integers when you have `NA`s in `z`. You can `round.` them (in which case you'll get a `DataArray` of `Float`s), but when you try to make them `Int` it will complain because `NA` can't be `Int64`.
Instead do

```
convert(DataArray{Int}, round.(z))
```

Also, it is nicer to post an example using data available in a package rather than a local dataset on your computer.

Comment: Frankly the treatment of missing values in Julia isn't yet ideal, but it's one of the most active areas of development.

Comment: Thanks, makes total sense now.  The error about no matching method signature, when my two examples reported the same type was throwing me.  I guess Julia has parallel types for collections that need to have NA's in them. As opposed to MATLAB having a whole parallel set of functions to handle NA's.

Comment: That's exactly right. I'ts going to change though, thankfully: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/announcement-an-update-on-dataframes-future-plans/4646